# Rewrite the function as a cross product.

Tags: functions

Good afternoon;

How can I write this subset function as cross product.

f : A → 2^B as a cross product.

Regards,

Comment: You mean interpreting $2^B$ as the set of functions $B\to\{F,T\}$?

Comment: Dear LutzL. Yes. set of function from B to A.

Answer (score 0):

This task plays with the two ways to interpret  $2^B$.

- The more common is as power set of $B$, i.e., the set of all subsets of B.
- The second related interpretation is as set of all maps from B into a set with two elements, $\{0,1\}$, $\{true, false\}$ or similar.

The two are related by the idea of an indicator function, $1_X(b)=1$ if and only if $b\in X$.

Now the function f has values that are functions on B, which can be refactored into a function of two variables.